# Need to match whole word completely from long set with no partials in Python

Tags: python, substring

I have a function that - as a larger part of a different program - checks to see if a word entry is in a text file.  So if the text file looks like this:

```
aardvark
aardvark's
aardvarks
abaci
.
.
.
zygotes
```

I just ran a quick if statement

```
infile = open("words","r")  #  Words is the file with all the words. . . yeah.
text = infile.read()

if word in text:
  return 1
else:
  return 0
```

Works, sort-of.  The problem is, while it returns true for aardvark, and false for wj;ek, it also will return true for any SUBSET of any word.  So, for example, the word rdva will come back as a 'word' because it IS in the file, as a subset of aardvark.  I need it to match whole words only, and I've been quite stumped.

So how can I have it match an entire word (which is equivalent to an entire line, here) or nothing?

I apologize if this question is answered elsewhere, I searched before I posted!

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each line and see if the whole line matches:

```
def in_dictionary(word):
  for line in open('words', 'r').readlines():
    if word == line.strip():
      return True

  return False
```

- When you use the `in` statement, you are basically asking whether the word is *in* the line.
- Using `==` matches the whole line.
- `.strip()` removes leading and trailing whitespace, which will cause `hello` to not equal `{space}hello`

Comment: This is clever, and I want to use it, but the for loop is going through the file by the letter, not by the word. . . any way I can specify where it breaks?  At returns instead of characters?

Comment: Actually, iterating over a **file object** iterates over lines by default; `.readlines()` is redundant. To go through the file by character, you'd have to explicitly `read()` it first (and thus find yourself iterating over a **string** a character at a time).

Comment: I originally had the `for line in open(...):` line, but for some reason that didn't work for @Terrik.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler approach. Your file is, conceptually, a list of words, so build that list of words (instead of a single string).

```
with open("words") as infile: words = infile.read().split()
return word in words
```

`<string> in <string>` does a substring search, but `<anything> in <list>` checks for membership. If you are going to check multiple times against the same list of words, then you may improve performance by instead storing a `set` of the words (just pass the list to the `set` constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Blender's answer works, but here is a different way that doesn't require you to iterate yourself:

Each line is going to end with a newline character (`\n`).  So, what you can do is put a `\n` before and after your checked string when comparing.  So something like this:

```
infile = open("words","r")  #  Words is the file with all the words. . . yeah.
text = "\n" + infile.read()     # add a newline before the file contents so we can check the first line

if "\n"+word+"\n" in text:
  return 1
else:
  return 0
```

Watch out, though -- your line endings may be `\r\n` or just `\r` too.

It could also have problems if the word you're checking CONTAINS a newline.  Blender's answer is better.

Comment: I don't think any normal words contain newlines ;)

Comment: You're assuming he's protecting against that possibility when feeding his check word into his function.

Answer (score 0):

That's all great until you want to verify every word in a longer text using that list. For me and `/usr/share/dict/words` it takes up to 3ms to check a single `word in words`. Therefore I suggest using a dictionary (no pun) instead. Lookups were about 2.5 thousand times faster with:

```
words = {}
for word in open('words', 'r').readlines():
    words[word.strip()] = True

def find(word):
    return word in words
```